# Using Constructor Arguments with Spring cache:annotation-driven

Tags: spring, spring-annotations

I receive the following exception when I add **cache:annotation-driven** to my application context:

```
Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

I have a class called **PersistController**, which has methods annotated with **@Cachable(..)**, and I am declaring an instance within the application context as follows:

```
<!-- The culprit, for whatever reason -->
<cache:annotation-driven />

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="primaryTest"/>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="secondaryTest"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- The problem began when I started requiring a String in the constructor. -->
<bean id="persistController" class="com.sei.poc.controller.PersistController" >
    <constructor-arg> <value>${cache.nextVersionPostfix}</value></constructor-arg>  
</bean>
```

When I remove the **cache:annotation-driven** line, the error goes away, and I instead receive an error indicating the annotated caching components are not working (obviously).  This means that the **PersistController** declared above is declared properly and Spring is fully capable of calling the proper constructor, resolving the property, and injecting the string as an argument.

So why the error when I add **cache:annotation-driven**?

I believe this has something to do with Spring automatically instantiating an instance of classes with **@Cacheable(..)**, or any of the Spring cache annotations.  If this is the case, I would like to know if there is a way I can specify my property as an argument in its construction.

If I cannot declare constructors for these classes, (and if you know the answer, I will assume you understand the spring-context-flow better than I) willl an **@Autowired** or **@Value(..)** annotation allow the generated class to detect the property?

Thank you all for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an answer to the second part of my question, whether or not an **@Value()** annotation with be resolved when spring loads the class with **cache:annotation-driven**.

The answer is yes, I had added the following line in my **PersistController** and the issue has been resolved:

```
@Value("${cache.currentVersionPostfix}")
private String keyPostfix;
```

I am still uncertain if I can supply an argument in a constructor loaded with **cache:annotation-driven**.  That being said, I will hold off on accepting this as an answer and accept one that answers that question.